# Page is not redirecting after update with ck editor

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, redirect

Im using CK editor. For database Im using mysql. But when i click on the submit button to submit the form the database is updating but the page is not redirecting to a different location.

```
  <?php 



  $sql="select * from automation_full";
  $query=mysql_query($sql_get);
  $row=mysql_fetch_object($query_get);
  $old_content=$row->column1;

  if(isset($_POST['save']))
  {
    $new_content=$_POST['content'];

    $sql="update table1 set content='$new_content' where key_id=1";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    if($query)
        {
            header("Location:index.php");
        }

  }


  ?>

    <div class="custom-container-right-form">



        <form action="#" method="post">


            <textarea id="text" name="content"></textarea>
             <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
            </script>

            <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="save" value="Update">


        </form>

    </div>
```

When i click on save it should update table1 and redirect to index.php . but my program is updating the table but not redirecting to index.php ... But when Im not using ck editor it works perfectly ok.... how to make it work with ck editor?

Comment: what error you get in console ?

Comment: No error what so ever... the query is running ok ... the table is updating as well... But after the query is being executed the page is not redirecting to index.php .... it rather stays in the same page  ....

Answer (score 0):

Change the `textarea` id as per your field name as:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **die() or exit()**

> Since **die() or exit()** after your
>
> ```
> header('Location:http://something')
> ```
>
> prevent it from  resulting in unexpected  behaviour.

```
if($query)
        {
            header("Location:index.php");
            die();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about echoing `<script>location.href=/page.php</script>` instead of the php header?
That only allows for redirection when no other content has been outputted, while this option redirects, no matter what, as soon as it gets written to the document.